# Is it possible to use method in lieu of a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In Objective-C is it possible to use a method in lieu of a block?

So for example, in stead of defining a block then calling the method:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
                           [self processTwitterSearchResponse:response data:responseData error:error];
                       }
 ];
```

Call the method directly:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:(processTwitterSearchResponse:response data:responseData error:error)
 ];
```

Or some such.

Comment: How hard is it to create a block that calls the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If the method takes a block as its handler, you need to give it a block. Why?

There are some methods that take function pointers instead of blocks, like NSArray’s `-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` (as opposed to the block-based `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`), but you definitely can’t just swap in a method signature where it expects a block.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer with the examples!

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

If the method is expecting a block, that's what you have to give it.

One way to understand this: blocks capture state (values of variables) from the place (lexical scope) where they are defined, allowing that state to be passed to another thread for deferred execution. That's why they are not interchangeable with a function pointer; there's more information being carried along with a block.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sensible question, just to add a little to the answers already given.

If you look at method which directly accepts another method as an argument you will note that it also takes an additional argument, the *object* to call the method on. Look at your block example and you will see it references `self`, so your block is providing the same pair of values - a method and an object.

There is absolutely no reason why Objective-C could not have a construct which took an object and a method, say `@block(object, method)` or even more simply just `object.method`, and returned a block but it does not have. If you are familiar with C# you will know it does have such a construct to produce a *delegate*, which is its version of a block.